# Use of "shim" in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I am new to RequireJS and wa just going through the following configuration code;

```
({
    appDir: "../",
    baseUrl: "js",
    dir: "../../appdirectory-build",
    paths: {
      jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.2',
      underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-1.4.4',
      backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-0.9.10',
      templates: '../templates',
      app: 'app'
    },

    shim: {
      underscore: {
        exports: '_'
      },
      backbone: {
        deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
        exports: "Backbone"
      }
    },
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main"
        }
    ]
})
```

I did not understand what exactly is the "shim" used for?
Could someone please explain me in simple terms.

Answer (score 2):

You can define non modular old scripts using shim config. By the non modular I mean the scripts those don't declare there dependencies using define(). So in the shim config in the above example you mention to load underscore and export it as '_' that means when the underscore is loaded it is accessible using _ in your application. And for backbone it means that before loading backbone, shim should ensure that underscore and jquery are loaded prior to backbone. Because underscore and jquery are the dependencies of the backbone, so shim is helping managing your dependencies of non modular scripts. After loading backbone export it as "Backbone" in your application.